# Injecting a provider into a module config

Tags: angularjs, syntax, dependency-injection

I have a provider named `TestProvider`

I'd like to configure my provider for my module.

This works:

```
app.config(function(testProviderProvider){
  // ...
}
```

This works not:

```
app.config(function(testProvider){
  // ...
}
```

I am injecting the same provider into a controller and it works:

```
function TestCtrl($scope,testProvider){
  // ..
}
```

WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official docs:

**provider(name, provider)**

```
Register a provider for a service. The providers can be retrieved and can have additional configuration methods.

Parameters
name – {string} – The name of the instance. NOTE: the provider will be available under name + 'Provider' key.
```

You should name your provider without "Provider" word.
This code works fine:

```
myApp.provider('test', function () {

});

myApp.config(function (testProvider) {

});
```

Comment: I find that confusing. Yet, i should have read the docs better. Thank you for your efforts.